# Removing extra comma when there's no first name in achemso bib style

Tags: bibtex, achemso

I have a reference where one of the authors is not a real person, so it doesn't have a first name, and the whole of it should be considered as "last name". When using the `achemso` package and bib style (with BibTeX), I get an extra comma after this "last name", supposedly to separate it from the non-existing first name. Is there some easy way (patching command, or specific formatting in the `bib` file) to avoid this comma?

Sample:

```
\documentclass[journal=jctcce]{achemso}
\title{Dummy Title}
\begin{document}
\cite{Coyote}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

```
@misc{Coyote,
  author = {{ACME Corporation} and Wile E. Coyote},
  title = {How to Catch a Road Runner},
}
```

[image]

(I mean the comma in `Corporation,;`.)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a fault in `achemso.bst`. Make a local copy of the file and change

```
names.str current.name.int "{vv~}{ll,}{~f.}{,~jj}" format.name$
```

to

```
names.str current.name.int "{vv~}{ll}{,~f.}{,~jj}" format.name$
```

I'll sort a fix out

Comment: Corrected for v3.13f